How to make the row numbers change when viewing a data-frame in RStudio and then sorting a particular column in the data-frame
In RStudio I am using the “View” function to see the data-frame visually and I see when I sort a column in the data-frame in descending/ascending order that the row numbers don’t change to reflect the sorting. I am not sure how to make the row numbers change when I sort a column.
Regards,
Anon9001.
library(jsonlite)
AHDI <- read.csv("https://ourworldindata.org/grapher/augmented-human-development-index.csv?v=1&csvType=full&useColumnShortNames=true")
View(AHDI)



Sorting the display of the data in the view pane does not change the ordering of the data frame. You can sort the actual data frame with the arrange() function from the dplyr package and then change the row names or, probably better, make a new column to store the row numbers. What are you trying to accomplish?

@FJCC I want the row numbers to reflect the sorting of the data in the view pane. Earlier I was able to do this by using the nest and unnest function of tidyr but now it doesn't work.

@FJCC I wonder whether making a new column to store the row numbers would fix this issue? I want it such that if I were to sort the column data in the view pane that the row numbers would change to reflect the order of the column values.  I don't want to use arrange function because I would like to sort the data-frame on whichever column I want to look at in the view pane.

@FJCC Hmm Nope creating a new column with the row numbers didn't work to fix my issue.

@FJCC To be more specific when I filter the data in view pane by year for example to 1980 and I sort the "ahdi" column I expect the row numbers to reflect the ranking of the "ahdi" column values in 1980.
I was able to do this quite easily with the nest/un-nest function of tidyr but with the recent version of RStudio this solution no longer works.

@FJCC Okay I figured out it's just a bug with the latest Rstudio version. The September version doesn't have this issue. Strange.
